# answer to sql ex ru number 57

Tags: sql

Hi I am trying to solve this particular question:

For classes having irreparable combat losses and at least three ships in the database, display the name of the class and the number of ships sunk.

based on this database:
The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database consists of the following relations: 
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement) 
Ships(name, class, launched) 
Battles(name, date) 
Outcomes(ship, battle, result) 
Ships in classes all have the same general design. A class is normally assigned either the name of the first ship built according to the corresponding design, or a name that is different from any ship name in the database. The ship whose name is assigned to a class is called a lead ship.
The Classes relation includes the name of the class, type (can be either bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country the ship was built in, the number of main guns, gun caliber (bore diameter in inches), and displacement (weight in tons). The Ships relation holds information about the ship name, the name of its corresponding class, and the year the ship was launched. The Battles relation contains names and dates of battles the ships participated in, and the Outcomes relation - the battle result for a given ship (may be sunk, damaged, or OK, the last value meaning the ship survived the battle unharmed). 
Notes: 1) The Outcomes relation may contain ships not present in the Ships relation. 2) A ship sunk can’t participate in later battles. 3) For historical reasons, lead ships are referred to as head ships in many exercises.4) A ship found in the Outcomes table but not in the Ships table is still considered in the database. This is true even if it is sunk.

here is the answer that I submitted, it did generate the correct result but it says "Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (less by 1)":

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.class, count(result)
  FROM classes c JOIN ships s ON
  c.class = s.class left join outcomes o on
   o.ship = s.name
WHERE result='sunk' 
   and c.class IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT c.class
            FROM classes c JOIN ships s ON
            c.class = s.class left join outcomes o on o.ship = s.name
           GROUP BY c.class
           HAVING count(name)>=3)
           group by c.class
           HAVING count(result) is not NULL
```

im not really sure where I went wrong ://

Comment: Side note: using `DISTINCT` on a subquery used for `IN` is at best pointless, and at worst, may trick the optimizer into doing *more* work than is necessary. The answer to `a IN (X, Y, Z, Y)` and `a IN (X, Y, Z)` is identical because `IN` is set based - duplicates don't matter.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, because your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

As your query brings information from T_Outcomes.C_Ships that might not be present in T_Ships.C_Ships, using an Inner Join might bring the information that is present in both T_Ships and T_Class but not in T_Outcomes. Your main table should've been T_Outcomes, as it supposedly has all C_Ships. You would have unclassified ships, however. Maybe:

`SELECT COALESCE(TC.C_Class, 'No_Class') AS Class, COUNT(*) AS ShipsSunk
    FROM T_Outcomes T0
         LEFT JOIN T_Ships TS ON T0.C_Ships = TS.C_Ships
         LEFT JOIN T_Classes TC on TS.C_Class = TC.C_Class
    WHERE C_Result = 'Sunk'
    GROUP BY COALESCE(TC.C_Class, 'No_Class')
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem description

```
For classes having irreparable combat losses and at least three ships in the database, display the name of the class and the number of ships sunk.
```

- For classes having irreparable combat losses

This means that the class should have at least one ship sunk, to get that you'll need the following query

```
  SELECT C.class, S.name, O.result FROM classes as C
  LEFT JOIN ships as S ON (C.class = S.class)
  LEFT JOIN outcomes as O ON (O.ship = S.name)
  WHERE O.result = 'sunk'
  UNION
  SELECT C.class, O.ship, O.result FROM classes as C
  LEFT JOIN outcomes as O ON (O.ship = C.class)
  WHERE O.result = 'sunk'
```

The first query joins the classes with the ships, and filters the ships to get only the sunk ones.

The second query gets the lead ships that aren't included in the ship table, and filters the ships to get only the sunk ones.

Later we need to group the ships by class and count them

```
WITH sunk_ships AS (
  SELECT C.class, S.name, O.result FROM classes as C
  LEFT JOIN ships as S ON (C.class = S.class)
  LEFT JOIN outcomes as O ON (O.ship = S.name)
  WHERE O.result = 'sunk'
  UNION
  SELECT C.class, O.ship, O.result FROM classes as C
  LEFT JOIN outcomes as O ON (O.ship = C.class)
  WHERE O.result = 'sunk'
),
clasess_with_sunk_ships AS (
 SELECT sships.class, COUNT(sships.result) sunk_count FROM sunk_ships sships
 GROUP BY sships.class
)
SELECT * FROM clasess_with_sunk_ships
```

- Classes with at least three ships in the database

First we need a list of all the ships

```
 SELECT C.class, S.name FROM classes as C
 JOIN ships as S ON (C.class = S.class)
 UNION
 SELECT C.class, O.ship FROM classes as C
 JOIN outcomes O ON (O.ship = C.class)
```

The first query joins the classes with the ships table.

The second query gets the lead ships that aren't included in the ship table

Having that list, we need to group the ships by class and filter the classes with at least 3 ships

```
all_ships AS (
 SELECT C.class, S.name FROM classes as C
 JOIN ships as S ON (C.class = S.class)
 UNION
 SELECT C.class, O.ship FROM classes as C
 JOIN outcomes O ON (O.ship = C.class)
),
classes_with_valid_count AS (
 SELECT aships.class, COUNT(aships.name) count FROM all_ships as aships
 GROUP BY aships.class
 HAVING COUNT(aships.name) >= 3
)
SELECT * FROM classes_with_valid_count
```

The join of `clasess_with_sunk_ships` and `classes_with_valid_count` will give us the right answer

```
WITH sunk_ships AS (
  SELECT C.class, S.name, O.result FROM classes as C
  LEFT JOIN ships as S ON (C.class = S.class)
  LEFT JOIN outcomes as O ON (O.ship = S.name)
  WHERE O.result = 'sunk'
  UNION
  SELECT C.class, O.ship, O.result FROM classes as C
  LEFT JOIN outcomes as O ON (O.ship = C.class)
  WHERE O.result = 'sunk'
),
clasess_with_sunk_ships AS (
 SELECT sships.class, COUNT(sships.result) sunk_count FROM sunk_ships sships
 GROUP BY sships.class
),
all_ships AS (
 SELECT C.class, S.name FROM classes as C
 JOIN ships as S ON (C.class = S.class)
 UNION
 SELECT C.class, O.ship FROM classes as C
 JOIN outcomes O ON (O.ship = C.class)
),
classes_with_valid_count AS (
 SELECT aships.class, COUNT(aships.name) count FROM all_ships as aships
 GROUP BY aships.class
 HAVING COUNT(aships.name) >= 3
)
SELECT cwsships.class, cwsships.sunk_count FROM clasess_with_sunk_ships cwsships
JOIN classes_with_valid_count cwvcount ON (cwvcount.class = cwsships.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is arising due to the bad database design (intentional) we can get around it by using this table instead of ships.

```sql
with tships as (
select class,name from ships
union
select ship as class,ship as name from outcomes where ship in (select class from classes)
)
```